# iTunes command+tab does not bring main window the foreground after command+h

Tags: macos, itunes

Related to : [Cmd-Tab does not bring iTunes to foreground](https://superuser.com/questions/94755/cmd-tab-does-not-bring-itunes-to-foreground)

There people claim that command+h will continue to work, but the behavior I'm seeing is:

- Launch a full screen Terminal instance (or anything else really)
- Launch a fresh iTunes
- command+h to hide it
- command+tab back to iTunes, this works and the main app window is given focus
- command+tab to Terminal
- command+tab to iTunes

What I expect to happen:

the main iTunes window is brought to the foreground and given focus.

What does happen:

The application menu bar shows iTunes, but an additional command+` is needed to bring the main app to foreground.

I thought it might have been related to a Chrome interaction, since I'm usually commmand+tabbing between my browser and everything else, but that does not seem to be the case.

I do have two "plugins" running:

- last.fm scrobbler
- Alfred app mini itunes player interface

Not sure if either of those create some phantom window or something that is mixing something up.

Versions of stuff:

- OS X: 10.6.5
- iTunes: 10.1.1 (4)
- last.fm: can't find it, but it's recent
- Alfred: 0.8 (89)

So after that big long rant, anyone else seeing this behavior?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. OSX 10.6.4, iTunes 10.1.1. No Alfred, just LaunchBar.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, probably in Dock.app, which is responsible for the application switcher, or maybe SystemUIServer, which is responsible for the UI.

This happens to me sometimes with various applications like Mail and Safari. I typically have very high resource usage on my machine, so that may be a contributing factor.

I cannot replicate this consistently using the steps you describe.

Is it 100% reproducible for you, after a restart and right from a fresh login?

This question will likely be closed unless you elaborate, since I don't think "does this happen for you?" fits within the scope of superuser.

Comment: I haven't attempted from a fresh restart, but like you I usually have a lot of stuff up and happening.  I asked here since googling for the behavior was getting a bit tricky.  If it needs to be closed, that's fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that worked for me. Open up a Terminal and get rid of your dock plist:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

Just a warning: this will reset your dock to the original settings, so things like size, position, and what icons display will be removed. It also reset my Spaces preferences.

Once you remove the plist, restart your machine, and you should be able to tab into iTunes.